# How to make launcher chooser pop up even the default launcher is set

Tags: java, android

I am doing a launcher app now, may I know how to make launcher chooser pop up even the default launcher is set? I know it is possible to choose two default launchers in Jelly Bean or above version, could anyone teach me how to do that? thanks.

my code is as below:-

```
        Intent selector = new Intent();
        selector.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        selector.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET );
        activity.startActivity(selector);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Intent selector = new Intent();
selector.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
selector.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET );
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(selector, "Select your app:"));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: sorry zozelfelfo, it is not working, the app will close when executing this code, and the chooser will pop up on the next time open...

Comment: Try it now :) I've added a `startActivity` statement by mistake

Comment: Thanks, it is working, but 'always' and 'just once' buttons are missing, may I know why?

Comment: Because this way you are forcing a Chooser no matter what, if you want  to hace "always" and "just once" you will need to clean your mobile preferences

Comment: yeah I know, but I think we can set more than one preferences for the same action, as I have a launcher app which set the same preferences with default launcher.